# Email confirm page missing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-2.1

I've followed [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#debug) to set up e-mail confirmation when creating an account with .NET Core 2.1. The problem is after registering, I go back to home page instead of some page saying "Confirmation email sent...". Is there such a page in the default UI or do I need to create it myself?

At the end of `OnPostAsync` in `Register.cshtml.cs`, this line `return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);` redirects to homepage, since `returnUrl` is null (and I don't understand how to change it either).

Can anyone point me in the right direction how to get a page telling the user that a confirmation e-mail has been sent?

Comment: I don't believe the templates include a confirmation page, but it would be easy to create.  Based on the [code](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/samples/IdentitySample.DefaultUI/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Register.cshtml.cs#L75) the action accepts a returnUrl parameter so you could pass in the url to the page that you created.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll do that!